why is it giving me invalid syntax in line 1 (python3.13)
code:
 print("Welcome to my Calculator!!")
 nb1 = int(input("Enter the 1st number: "))
 nb2 = int(input("Enter the 2nd number: "))
 A = nb1 + nb2 
 S = nb1 - nb2
 M = nb1*nb2
 D = nb1//nb2
 print("The addition of " , nb1 , "+" , nb2 ,"is:", A)
 print("The subtraction of " , nb1 , "-" , nb2 ,"is:", S)
 print("The multiplication of " , nb1 , "x" , nb2 ,"is:", M)
 print("The division of " , nb1 , "/" , nb2 ,"is:", D)

tbh i don't know what to do. it only worked in python debugger
error message:
 File "<python-input-21>", line 1
    & C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/python.exe "c:/Users/user1/Desktop/homework 2.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>


You're trying to run this:
C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/python.exe "c:/Users/user1/Desktop/homework 2.py"

as if it were python code.
That is a command, to be entered at a command prompt.  It isn't python code.
